# use php code in the text ( add read more link in text) wordpress

Tags: wordpress, text, hyperlink

i need a one format like `the_permalink` for add read more link in the text

but this is a php and **not work in the wordpress editor**

**i'm need 1 format for use in word press editor**

```
<a href=”‘.get_permalink().’” rel=”nofollow”><span>check this</span></a>
```

**the_permalink Not work in wordpress editor for use
in text?????**

how can i do ???

can i add link in text to read more ?

Comment: What you intend to do?if you just want to put a readmore link, use <!--more-->

Answer (score 0):

You wrap it in `<?php` tags so the PHP preprocessor can render it:

```
<a href=”<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>” rel=”nofollow”><span>check this</span></a>
```

I'm not sure if you need the `echo` there, so if it doesn't work, get rid of `echo` and it should print out just fine.

Comment: I'm use as   ( <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Click</a> )    and   ( <a href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>">Click</a> )   >>>> But Not work >>> not show any link